# About the Excavator Badge

Tags: discussion, badges

That badge refers to "Edit first post that was inactive for 6 months". I'm confused of the meaning of first post. Do it refers to my post or someone's post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It refers to the first time to edit a post that was inactive for 6 months. It doesn't need to be someone's first post. It really means that you get the badge the first time you do that, and only that first time.

Comment: @juniven just so you know, unnecessary edits of old posts are frowned upon.

Comment: @quid I know. I never did unnecessary edits of old posts.